# Powerapps model-diven app: Is it possible to add a View to the left menu?

Tags: view, powerapps, model-driven

Hi I can't figure out how to add different tableviews  from the same table to the left menu in a model-driven powerapp. Is it possible to add different views to the menu or can one just add tabels? If its possible, please explain how one does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a url that points to a particular view and add it to the sitemap. Here is how this URL can look like:

```
/main.aspx?etn={entity}&pagetype=entitylist&viewid={view id}&viewtype=1039
```

Example:

```
/main.aspx?etn=opportunity&pagetype=entitylist&viewid=%7b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010003006%7d&viewtype=1039
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. It opens the url to the view directly, but sadly opens up a new tab each time. So i cant use it :(.  I had to add the domain to the link. The system says that it can only accept urls that start with http/https.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of how you configured the link embedding?

Comment: Hi, i manager to make it work by using the old powerapps sitemap area. Thanks for the help, it solved my problem 